# Get keys of every object and insert that data into array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-bootstrap, react-props

I want to get the keys of every frame object and insert that data into array. After it should have arrays in array. I have tried multiple ways and have not figured it out. Any suggestions?
This is the output.json that i will be working with, it could go up to 550 frame number's.

```
[{"frame_number": 1, "roi0": [101.78202823559488, 99.39509279584912, 49.546951219239915, 29.728170731543948], "intensity0": 80.0, "roi1": [101.78202823559488, 99.39509279584912, 49.546951219239915, 29.728170731543948], "intensity1": 157.0},
{"frame_number": 2, "roi0": [102.56623228630755, 97.95906005049548, 50.25603182631066, 30.153619095786393], "intensity0": 80.0, "roi1": [102.56623228630755, 97.95906005049548, 50.25603182631066, 30.153619095786393], "intensity1": 158.0},
{"frame_number": 3, "roi0": [103.39336535376313, 98.20468223716023, 49.58465295946593, 29.750791775679556], "intensity0": 80.0, "roi1": [103.39336535376313, 98.20468223716023, 49.58465295946593, 29.750791775679556], "intensity1": 157.0},
```

The following is my app.js where i get the output.json file from the api and send it through to a component, button_footer

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import React from "react";
import Radio_Button from "./components/Radio_Button.js";
import Buttons_Footer from "./components/Buttons_Footer.js";
import LeftPane from "./components/LeftPane.js";

//import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { apiResponse: [] };

  }
  // Comunicate with API
  callAPI() {
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/IntensityAPI") //React app talks to API at this url
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ apiResponse: res }));
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.callAPI();
  }
  render() {
    return (

      <div className="App">

        <header className="App-header">
          <p></p>
          <div class="row fixed-bottom no-gutters">
            <div class="col-3 fixed-top fixed-bottom">

              <LeftPane></LeftPane>
            </div>
            <div class="offset-md-3" >
            <Buttons_Footer readings =   {this.state.apiResponse}/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

The following is the button_footer which is where I tried to handle this data and put it in a array but failed.

````
import $ from "jquery";
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { MDBFormInline } from 'mdbreact';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import Radio_Button from "./Radio_Button.js";
// Footer Component with checkbox's used to select region/region's of interest 
class Buttons_Footer extends Component {
  // Enables the Functionality of the "Select Multiple Region's" switch using jquerys
  componentDidMount() {
    $(".region").click(function(e){
    if($('#customSwitches').is(':not(:checked)')){
      if($('.region:checked').length > 1){ // Multiply regions unable to be selected
        alert('You can not check multiple');
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
});

$("#customSwitches").click(function(e){ // Multiply regions able to be selected
   $(".region").prop('checked', false);
}); }

//<p>{this.props.region.roi0}</p>
  render() {
    return (
      <Container class = "container  offset-md-3" > 
            <div className='custom-control custom-switch' >
            <input type='checkbox' className='custom-control-input' id='customSwitches' />
            <label  className='custom-control-label' htmlFor='customSwitches'>
                 Select Multiple Region's
            </label> 
            {this.props.readings.map((region)=>{
              return <Radio_Button region ={region} key ={region.frame_number}/>
            })}
            Object.keys({this.props.readings}).map((key, index) => {
  const myItem = myObject[key]
  return <MyComponent myItem={myItem} key={index} />
})
              <MDBFormInline>
                <input class="region" type="checkbox" name="region1" value="1" />
                <label for="region1"> 1</label>
                <input class="region" type="checkbox" name="region2" value="2" />
                <label for="region2"> 2</label>
             </MDBFormInline>
            </div>      
    </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default Buttons_Footer;

```
````

Comment: whick key do you want to get? I see no key of every object

Comment: @iamhuynq I want all the keys, such that i was giving instructions,            
  assuming that I don't know how many roi's will be in response:

Get keys of every frame object and insert that data into array.                                    After that you should have arrays in array.
Filter keys with regex.
For each key that's left show button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this work

```
this.props.readings.map((reading, index) => {
   Object.keys(reading).map((key, index) => {
       const myItem = reading[key]
      return <MyComponent myItem={myItem} key={index} />
   })
})
```

Comment: Thank you, and how would i check in the MyComponent if it worked correctly, like would i say ```<p>{this.props.myItem} </p>````

Comment: Maybe `<p>{ this.props.myItem ? this.props.myItem : 'something wrong' }</p>`

Comment: Also is my initial state for apiResponse, [ ] , correct? Thanks for your help @iamhuynq